# Implication of independence and conditional independence

Tags: probability

Prove that if A and B are independent and conditionally independent given C, then A is independent of C or B is independent of C. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you at least _edit_ your problem statement to include the definitions of independence and conditional independence so that everyone is in the same page? Does some thing pop out at you when you write equations instead of words?

Answer (score 0):

The proposition is false. As a counterexample define a vector $C= (A,B)$ and assume that A and B are independent random variables. In this case the two variables are trivially conditionally independent because they are both constants given C. However, clearly C is dependent on A and C is dependent on B.